# Display datepicker instead of list in JQueryUI's autocomplete's pop-widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

For the search functionality of my webapp, instead of multiple input fields I'm giving my users a single field to enter their query, and they can use special syntax to make their queries more specific. To ease the process of writing these queries, I'm using the [JQueryUI's autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete). As the user type, I'm parsing their query, determine the context of what they are currently typing, and give them relevnat autocomplete. For example - if the user is using the syntax for filtering by client, I give them a list of all the clients(filtered by the partial client name they have already written ofcourse).

That part I implemented and it works great. Now, some of the fields I'm filtering by are date fields. There is sense in giving a suggestion list for these, but I do want to allow my users to enter those dates using [JQueryUI's datepicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker). I've considered using [_renderMenu](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderMenu), but as far as I understand I need to use widget factory for this(which seems like a overkill), and I can't tell how to call the normal behavior for regular list completions if I override `_renderMenu`.

I've managed to work out a hacky solution - open the pop-widget with a blank array and use the [`open` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open) to add the datepicker. This works, but I have to pass the instruction to create a datepicker instead of using the regular widget via [JQuery's in-DOM data storage](http://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/data-storage/), which just feels hacky...

Is there any proper way to do what I want?

**UPDATE(a bit off-topic)**
Zee Tee wanted to know in the comments how exactly I determine when to regular autocomplete list and when to open datepicker, since I'm using a single field for both. Well, the text in a field is actually a query, which I parse on client-side and therefore have full access to it's abstract sytnax tree in my JavaScript code. I made the syntax very relaxed, so I can parse half-queries and still get valid ASTs. When I do an autocomplete, I take the part of the query **before** the caret and parse it. Then I down-right in the syntax tree until I find something I can autocomplete.

For example - lets say I have a query `client=jack date<`, and the caret is at the end. I parse it to something like:

```
and:
  - equals:
    - field: client
    - text: jack
  - less-than:
    - field: date
    - text:
```

I can't provide autocompletion for `and`, so I have to go down-right in the AST, to `less-than`. This is a pattern that I recognize as datepicker pattern, so I display a datepicker. If the caret was at the middle of the word "jack", I would get this AST:

```
- equals:
  - field: client
  - text: ja
```

Which I would recognize as a pattern for displaying the list of clients, filtered by "ja".

So - determining **what** to display is easy - the problem is **how**.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand this correctly, but how are you going to make datepicker go inside an autocomplete list, or determine when to open each one by just using one field?

Comment: @ZeeTee I currently make the datepicker go inside an autocomplete list by modifying the list after JQueryUI opens it as as regular autocomplete list. That's a hacky solution, and I'm looking for a better one. As for how I determine what to display - that's a bit more complex, so I've updated the question.